# Using duritong/puppet-shorewall with Puppet and Hiera does not work as expected

Tags: puppet, hiera

I am trying to use this module here with puppet: https://github.com/duritong/puppet-shorewall

Following the example I got the rules working

```
node xy {
    class{'config::site_shorewall':
      startup => "0"  # create shorewall ruleset but don't startup
  }
    shorewall::rule {
        'incoming-ssh': source => 'all', destination => '$FW',  action  => 'SSH(ACCEPT)', order => 200;
        'incoming-puppetmaster': source => 'all', destination => '$FW',  action  => 'Puppetmaster(ACCEPT)', order => 300;
        'incoming-imap': source => 'all', destination => '$FW',  action  => 'IMAP(ACCEPT)', order => 300;
        'incoming-smtp': source => 'all', destination => '$FW',  action  => 'SMTP(ACCEPT)', order => 300;
    }
}
```

Now I want to pack this into hiera. With some research I found this explanation here how to convert the different variables into hiera hashes:  http://puppetlunch.com/puppet/hiera.html

Now when the original example is converted to hiera it should look like this, if I am not wrong (there are only 2 examples in hiera):

```
---                                                                                                                    
classes:
  - shorewall

shorewall::rule:
    incoming-ssh:
        source:   'all'
        destination: '$FW'
        action:   'SSH(ACCEPT)'
        order:    '200'
    incoming-puppetmaster:
        source:     'all'
        destination:    '$FW'
        action:     'Puppetmaster(ACCEPT)'
        order:      200
```

What could be the problem that there is no data except the header and footer in the config files?

cat /etc/shorewall/puppet/rules

```
#
# Shorewall version 3.4 - Rules File
#
# For information on the settings in this file, type "man shorewall-rules"
#
# See http://shorewall.net/Documentation.htm#Rules for additional information.
#
#############################################################################################################
#ACTION SOURCE          DEST            PROTO   DEST    SOURCE          ORIGINAL        RATE            USER/   MARK
#                                               PORT    PORT(S)         DEST            LIMIT           GROUP
#LAST LINE -- ADD YOUR ENTRIES BEFORE THIS ONE -- DO NOT REMOVE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modeling the resources in Hiera is only half the cake. You must instruct Puppet to convert this data back into actual resources.

```
$data = hiera('shorewall::rule', {})
create_resources('shorewall::rule', $data)
```

Key is the [create_resources function](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#createresources).

You should not use `shorewall::rule` as the name of your Hiera key, it's misleading. Use a name that does not resemble actual syntax, e.g.

```
shorewall_rules:
    incoming-ssh:
       ...
```

And in the manifest

```
$data = hiera('shorewall_rules', {})
```